# How to make redirect only without query parameters on nginx?

Tags: nginx

I try to make redirect from location only if they don't have arguments. If they have arguments, server should return URI with that args.

I tried this option, but with this setting the redirect from the page without parameters works correctly, and the URL with the parameters returns 404:

```
    location = /foo/ {
        if ($args = "") {
            return 301 domain.com;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$is_args`

> if a request line has arguments, or an empty string otherwise

```
location = /foo/ {
    if ($is_args = "") {
        return 301 domain.com;
    }
}
```

Comment: this does work tho you need to delete block `error_page 404` [update]
what I want to say is, you either make a `/foo` file or do that above ^

Comment: On our site all search queries has URLs like /catalog/?search=something.
Page /catalog/ don't have any content. I want to make redirect from domain.com/catalog/ to domain.com because that want our SEO-specialist.